# pygame error , pygame can't read file sound

Tags: python, pygame

```py
import pygame
from pygame import *
    
WINDOWSIZE = (500,600)
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 512)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWSIZE))
pygame.display.set_caption("Menu")
    
pygame.init() 
pygame.mixer.set_num_channels(64)
pygame.mixer.music.load('music.wav')
```

error:

> ```
> pygame.mixer.music.load('music.wav')
>  pygame.error: Unknown WAVE format
> ```

Comment: you may have to check if file is correct. Maybe it is not `wav` but other format but with wrong file extension. OR maybe it is `wav` but with different parameters - `pygame` may need uncompressed `wav`. `pygame` may prefer `ogg` format.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that there is no music playing in your code.
I think you should play the music after you load it.

```
import pygame

from pygame import *
WINDOWSIZE = (500,600)
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 512)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWSIZE))
pygame.display.set_caption("Menu")
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.set_num_channels(64)
pygame.mixer.music.load('music.wav')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Of course, we have to make sure that the program is running when the music is playing, otherwise the program will end up running before the music is playing!

Comment: Please learn how to format the code.  See [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Snippets are only for html/javascript/css

Comment: it cant load so how can it play?